# Clustering similar words in different sets

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering

Suppose I have $N$ sets as follow:
$$S_1 = \{a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n\}$$
$$S_2 = \{b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_n\}$$
$$S_3 = \{c_1,c_2,\cdots,c_n\}$$
$$\vdots$$
elements of each set (i.e., $a_n$, $b_n$, $c_n$ and etc) are words. I want to go through all the sets and cluster similar words. So we may have $M$ number of clusters ($C$) with different lengths, for example:
$$C_1 = \{a_1,b_5,c_2,\cdots\}$$
$$C_2 = \{c_1,a_2\}$$

My idea was to take cosine similarity between all words on all sets, but if you have too many words and many sets this will not be a good idea. I wonder if there is a clustering method for such scenario?

One other idea might be just to flatten the sets and using standard clustering techniques, but then question is how do we keep track of the sets? namely it is vital for me to know which words came from which set.

Comment: If you have too many words how do you think track all of them?

Comment: @Allan yes indeed that's part of the problem

Comment: Try using hierarchical clustering with all datasets flatanned, I think it could work.

Comment: What is flattening a set? Please add a short explanation to the Q.

Comment: How do you estimate the amount of similarity between each two words?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear to me. Keeping track of sets and words is independent of whether you flatten or not, you just need a mapping from words to sets (and presumably vice versa) in some data structure, then given a clustering of the words you can use that data structure to find the associations in the form you need them. The second issue is what is your essential problem: is it that you want to avoid doing an all vs all comparison on all the words? A simple approach would be to do all vs all comparison on the words, use some similarity for each comparison, use a cut-off, represent this as a network, and apply graph clustering (aka community detection). Protein sequence clustering is an example of a  similar problem.